# Override EC2 Image ID for AWS Batch Compute Environment - on AWS CDK Stack

Tags: amazon-ec2, gpu, aws-cdk, amazon-ami, aws-batch

I'm creating a CloudFormation Stack using AWS CDK (for Python) and one of its main components is a Batch Compute Environment which should run GPU intensive jobs.

Batch jobs would simply not work with GPU unless I manually set up the `EC2 configuration`, option under `Additional configuration` when manually creating a Batch Compute Environment (see image below).

[image]

Now, I don't want to do that manually, I want to be able to define this in my CDK Stack. Right now, I have something like this:

```py
ecs_machine_image = batch.EcsMachineImage(
    # image="ami-0d625ab7e92ab3a43",
    image_type=batch.EcsMachineImageType.ECS_AL2_NVIDIA
)

compute_env_1 = batch.ManagedEc2EcsComputeEnvironment(
    scope=self,
    id=f"{stack_id}-compute-env",
    vpc=vpc,
    instance_types=[
        ec2.InstanceType("g4dn.2xlarge"),
    ],
    images=[ecs_machine_image],
    maxv_cpus=32,
    minv_cpus=0,
    security_groups=[security_group],
    service_role=batch_service_role,
    instance_role=ecs_instance_role,
)
```

The comment `# image="ami-0d625ab7e92ab3a43"` is to illustrate that I thought it would be possible to pass the AMI image id directly to `batch.EcsMachineImage`, but it isn't.

In summary, my question is: Using AWS CDK configuration, how can I define a specific AMI image to be used by all jobs running in the Batch Compute Environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image` property accepts the [IMachineImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.EcsMachineImage.html#image) interface type.  The EC2 [MachineImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/MachineImage.html) class has a static method [generic_linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/MachineImage.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux) that accepts a map of AMIs by region and returns the expected  `IMachineImage`:

```py
image=ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux({'us-east-1': 'ami-12345678'})
```

Comment: thank you fedonev! Now, would you know a way to do this without necessarily using the region mapping? Since it should always be the same AMI regardless... or, alternatively, to have teh region name automatically retrieved from the Stack's deploy region?

Comment: Glad to help, @LuizTauffer.  AMIs are bound to a region, so there's no avoiding the map.  But you can certainly use python code to create the map dynamically.  Stack instances have a [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Stack.html#aws_cdk.Stack.region) property that resolves to its region name.